# How to save to SQL Server Express database in visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express, sqldatasource

I am a beginner in vb.net and would like to know how to connect a window form to a SQL Server Express database in Visual Studio 2005 so that we can later on perform add, search, update and delete on a record.

here is my code:

```
Dim mycommand As SqlCommand
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader
Dim ra As Integer

Private Sub cmdsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles cmdsave.Click

    Using myconnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\database\app.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        myconnection.Open()
        mycommand = New SqlCommand("insert into staff([FirstName],[LastName],[Address],[DOB], " & _
                                   "[TelephoneNum], [DateJoinIn], [HighestQualifi], [AppointedAs], [Salary]) " & _
                                   "VALUES (@first, @last, @address, @dob, @tel, @dateJ, @highQ, @appointed, @sal)", myconnection)

        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", txtfname.Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", txtlname.Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", txtdob.Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", txttelephone.Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateJ", txtdjoinin.Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@highQ", txthqualifi.Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appointed", txtappoint.text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sal", txtsalary.Text)
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        myconnection.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
```

The problem is that it is not saving in my database????? pls help out

Answer (score 0):

As I've said before on this site - the whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myconnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MyAppDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyAppDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: @Shray: my next step would be to put the call to `mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` into a `try...catch` block to see if an exception happens - and if so, what it is and what it tells me

Comment: @Shray: furthermore: the `mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` also has a return value of type `int` - it tells you how many rows were affected (e.g. inserted) - what value are you getting for that return value??